# Export table data to Excel using a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, excel, export

How to export SQL Server table data to an Excel sheet?

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO

RECONFIGURE;
GO

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO

RECONFIGURE;
GO

EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO     

EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO

INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Desktop\NHLeads.xlsx;', 
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') 
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.LeadTicket
```

I used the above query but I get this error:

> The 32-bit OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server.

Comment: Use the 64-bit driver, not the 32-bit one; your instance is 64-bit.

Comment: @Larnu can i use office 64bit instead of 32bit ?

Comment: You don't use office, no; you need install the 64-bit ACE OLEDB drivers.

Comment: @Larnu still have the same issue after installing 64-bit ACE OLEDB drivers

Comment: If you got the same error, you aren't using the 64-bit driver. Did you change the name of the driver to the appropriate new one in your SQL?

Comment: No, i just download it from here [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255] then installed it

Comment: No good installing it of you don't update your code to use it @hashim . Update your statement to use the 64-bit driver.